# Qt Release application with PSQL database - error on loading driver

Tags: windows, qt, psql

With QtCreator (for version 57) I created simple application that connects to DB and waits for notifications. There isn't realy much code for it and all of it works on LINUX:

```
MyDataBase = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL", "Main"));
```

Unfortunetly after transitioning from Linux to Windows (on which app will by mainy used) I encounteredd some issues. As usuall, missign dlls, but those were quick fast (copy-paste given .dll). Now I can't run this still on Windows, because it refuses to connect to db. With system's variable I managed to find more. Now even when I see error I can't even grasp what else could I do to make it work:

```
Found metadata in lib C:/_Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsqld.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QSqlDriverFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "QPSQL7",
            "QPSQL"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QPSQLDriverPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 329472
}
```

> "The plugin 'C:/_Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsqld.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)" 
>                not a plugin

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "D:/QT_Notifi/build-Notifier-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/sqldrivers" ...
loaded library "C:/_Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll"

QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "C:/_Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll" : "Cannot load library C:\\_Qt\\5.7\\mingw53_32\\plugins\\sqldrivers\\qsqlpsql.dll: %1 is not correct application of Win32."

QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded

QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```